# How to divide the results of two different echos in two different html elements by using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using AJAX to query the database from php file.... The result of the database query should then be put in two different html textareas. This is my code:

javascript :

```
function ajax_post(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "displaypatientmessage.php";
var fn = document.getElementById("title").value;
//var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
var vars = "title="+fn;

hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status     div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

php

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","askthedoctor");
$sql="select patient_text, doctor_text from messages where     title='".$title."';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
?>
```

form

```
<form>
   <table id="table" class="table">
      <tr>
         <th>Messages</th>
         <th>Problem Description</th>
         <th>Doctor's Answer</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th><select id="title">
               <?php   
$sql="select title from messages where paitient_id=(select id from login where username='".$username."');";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
               <?php echo "<option value=\"mesazhi1\">".$row[0]."</option>";}?>
            </select>
         </th>
         <td><textarea rows="17.95" col="100" id ="question" > </textarea></td>
         <td><textarea rows="17.95" col="100" id ="answer" readonly> </textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="button" name="openmessage" value="Display Selected Message" onClick="ajax_post();"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Now I want that echo `$row[0]` to be put in question textarea
and echo `$row[1]` to be put in answer textarea

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: What format is your AJAX response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two outputs with a character like `~`.

```
echo $row[0] . '~' . $row[1];
```

And in javascript code, split the response by `~` like this:

```
var return_data = hr.responseText;
var temp = return_data.split('~');
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = temp[0];
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = temp[1];
```

Basic concept is:

You need to pass multiple strings through AJAX, not a single one.

Join two strings with a character.

In the javascript end, explode (split) the output by `~`.

Here, you get array.

First element of array is question and second is answer thats it.

Very simple!!!

Comment: Or better yet, return the rows as a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing text like that, just return a json object.

Use the php function `json_encode` to encode an array to json:

`json_encode(array('question' => $row[0], 'answer' => $row[1]));`

Then in your success function you parse the result to a javascript object like this:

`var result = JSON.parse(result);`

Then you can access your rows doing the following to populate your fields

`result.question; result.answer`;

The reason why your current code is not working is that your ajax query expects 1 result. So it does not recognise your two echoes as a pair.

EDIT:

Also use jQuery, vanilla javascript is bulky and ugly.